# Yii: request methods

Tags: php, yii

I have a table with title and done and id fields,
Now the problem is that when I click on the add button, the data is not stored in the table and the data is not displayed, if you test this code and create a task model with gii, you will see that add button does not work that is when you type a name and click on add button, the task will not be added
Fields related to this model: id, title, done
I have the following code:

**todo.js in the assets file**

```
var todo = {
     taskTemplate: null,
     refs: {},
     options: {},
     reload: function(){
     $.ajax({
     url: todo.options.taskEndpoint,
     type: 'get',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(response) {
        $.each(response.data, function(index, value){
            todo.refs.tasks.append(todo.taskTemplate(value));
        });
     },
        error: todo.onFailure
    });
 },
 onFailure: function(xhr){
     var data = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
     todo.refs.status.text('');
     $.each(data.errors, function(index, value){
        todo.refs.status.append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
     });
 },
 onAdd: function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var form = this;
     $.ajax({
         url: todo.options.taskEndpoint,
         type: 'post',
         data: $(form).serialize(),
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(response) {
            todo.refs.tasks.append(
                todo.taskTemplate(response.data));
                form.reset();
            },
         error: todo.onFailure
     });
 },
 onDelete: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();var id = $(this).parents('.task').attr('data-id');
     $.ajax({
         url: todo.options.taskEndpoint,
         type: 'delete',
         data: {
            id: id
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function() {
            $('.task[data-id='+id+']').remove();
         },
         error: todo.onFailure
    });
 },
 onChange: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var data = {
        id: $(this).parents('.task').attr('data-id'),
        Task: {}
     };
     if(this.type==='checkbox') {
        data.Task.done = + this.checked;
     }
     else if(this.type==='text') {
        data.Task.title = $(this).val();
     }
     $.ajax({
         url: todo.options.taskEndpoint,
         type: 'put',
         data: data,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(response) {
            $('.task[data-id='+response.data.id+']')
             .before(todo.taskTemplate(response.data))
            .remove();
         },
         error: todo.onFailure
     });
 },
 initLoader: function() {
     var loadingText = 'Loading...';
     $(document).ajaxSend(function(){
        todo.refs.status.text(loadingText);}).ajaxStop(function(){
        if(todo.refs.status.text()===loadingText) {
        todo.refs.status.fadeOut(500, function(){
            todo.refs.status.text('').show();
        });
      }
    });
 },
 bindEvents: function() {
 todo.refs.taskForm.submit(todo.onAdd);
 todo.refs.tasks.on('click', '.delete', todo.onDelete);
 todo.refs.tasks.on('change', 'input', todo.onChange);
 },
 initRefs: function() {
 todo.refs.page = $('.todo-index');
 todo.refs.tasks = todo.refs.page.find('.tasks');
 todo.refs.status = todo.refs.page.find('.status');
 todo.refs.taskForm = todo.refs.page.find('.new-taskform');
 },
 init: function(options){
 todo.options = options;
 todo.taskTemplate = doT.template($('#template-task').html());
 todo.initRefs();
 todo.initLoader();
 todo.bindEvents();
 todo.reload();
 }
};
```

**controller**

```
<?php

class TodoController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
     {
         $task = new Task();
         $this->render('index', array(
         'task' => $task,
         ));
     }

     public function actionTask()
     {
         $req = Yii::app()->request;
            if($req->isPostRequest) {
                $this->handlePost($req->getPost('id'), 
                $req->getPost('Task'));
            }
            elseif($req->isPutRequest) {
                $this->handlePut($req->getPut('Task'));

            }
            elseif($req->isDeleteRequest) {
                $this->handleDelete($req->getDelete('id'));
            }
            else {
             $this->handleGet($req->getParam('id'));
            }
     }

     private function handleGet($id)
     {
         if($id) {
             $task = $this->loadModel($id);
             $this->sendResponse($task->attributes);
         }
         else {
             $data = array();
             $tasks = Task::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'id'));
             foreach($tasks as $task) {
                 $data[] = $task->attributes;
             }
            $this->sendResponse($data);
         }
     }

     private function handlePut($data)
     {
         $task = new Task();
         $this->saveTask($task, $data);
     }

     private function handlePost($id, $data)
     {
         $task = $this->loadModel($id);
         $this->saveTask($task, $data);
     }

     private function saveTask($task, $data)
     {
         if(!is_array($data)){
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 400, array('No data
                provided.'));
         }
         // $task->setAttributes($data);
         $task->attributes = $data;
         if($task->save()) {
            $this->sendResponse($task->attributes);
         } else {
            $errors = array();
                foreach($task->errors as $fieldErrors) {
                    foreach($fieldErrors as $error) {
                        $errors[] = $error;
                    }
                }
            $this->sendResponse(array(), 400, $errors);
         }
     }

     private function handleDelete($id)
     {
         $task = $this->loadModel($id);
         if($task->delete()) {
             $this->sendResponse('OK');
         }
         else {
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 500, array('Unable to
             delete task.'));
         }
     }

     private function loadModel($id)
     {
         $task = Task::model()->findByPk($id);
         if(!$task) {
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 404, array('Task not
             found.'));
         }
         return $task;
     }

     private function sendResponse($data, $responseCode = 200,
    $errors = array())
     {
         $messages = array(
         200 => 'OK',
         400 => 'Bad Request',
         404 => 'Not Found',
         500 => 'Internal Server Error',
         );
         if(in_array($responseCode, array_keys($messages))) {
             header("HTTP/1.0 $responseCode ".$messages[$responseCode],
            true, $responseCode);
         }
         echo json_encode(array(
             'errors' => $errors,
             'data' => $data,
             ));
         Yii::app()->end();
     }
}

?>
```

**view**

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('todo');
    $options = json_encode(array(
    'taskEndpoint' => $this->createUrl('todo/task'),
));
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('todo', "todo.
init($options);", CClientScript::POS_READY);
?>
<div class="todo-index">
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="tasks"></div>
    <div class="new-task">
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm('todo/task')?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($task, 'title')?>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Add')?>
    <?php echo CHtml::endForm()?>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="template-task" type="text/x-dot-template">
    <div class="task{{? it.done==1}} done{{?}}" data-id="{{!it.
id}}">
    <input type="checkbox"{{? it.done==1}}checked {{?}}/>
    <input type="text" value="{{!it.title}}" />
    <a href="#delete" class="delete">Remove</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Can anyone help ?